# How can we add multiple users to a group by single command in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, users, group

I have to use

```
usermod -G groupname username
```

everytime to add user to group.
Isn't there any way to do it by single line like

```
usermod -G groupname user1,user2,user3
```

Comment: Why does it need to be a single line? The `usermod` utility only takes one username as its last argument.

Comment: Instead of usermod, Is there any command to achieve that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *set* the member list of a group with one command:

```
gpasswd -M user1,user2,user3,... groupname
```

But to add using this, you'll need to get the existing list:

```
gpasswd -M "$(getent group groupname | awk -F: '$4 {print $4","}')"user1,user2,user3,... groupname
```

But it's just easier to use `xargs` or loops manually:

```
for u in user1 user2 ...
do
    gpasswd -a "$u" groupname
done
```

Or:

```
$ cat file
user1
user2
...
$ xargs -a file -n 1 gpasswd groupname -a
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use bash brace expansion with eval

```
eval 'usermod -aG groupname '{user1,user2,user3}';'
```

or loop the command

```
for i in user1 user2 user3; do usermod -aG groupname $i; done
```

Note: `-G` sets the group(s) for the user while `-aG` appends the group(s).

Comment: `eval 'sudo usermod -aG groupname '{user1,user2,user3}';'` is probably a little better: it adds users to the group instead of changing their group membership

Comment: @Shōgun8 Yes, indeed. Thanks!